# Problems with UnregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener in android

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-preferences, preferences, android-sharedpreferences

I am creating a basic settings page and my code works fine till now. But when i add UnregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener at Onpause it starts giving errors. Insight is required that what i am doing wrong and where should i insert the unregister. All the codes are presented below. I would be happy if you guys could test it out in Android Studio. Any help would be appreciated. I am trying to avoid using deprecated code but if no alternatives i will use it as last resort.

Main Activity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView settingsValue;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



    final Button startsettings = (Button)findViewById(R.id.startsettings);
    settingsValue=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);

    startsettings.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,SettingsActivity.class));MainActivity.this.finish();}
    });

}}
```

SettingsActivity.java

```
public class SettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity {

static SharedPreferences sharedPreferences12;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    sharedPreferences12 = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);



    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content,new SettingsFragment()).commit();

}

public static class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment implements SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener
{
    Context context;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.custompreferences);

        context=getActivity();

        Preference prefalarm = findPreference("key_ringtone_alarm");
        Ringtone ringtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getActivity(),Uri.parse(sharedPreferences12.getString("key_ringtone_alarm","")));
        prefalarm.setSummary(ringtone.getTitle(getActivity()));

        Preference prefnoti = findPreference("key_ringtone_notification");
        Ringtone ringtonenoti = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getActivity(),Uri.parse(sharedPreferences12.getString("key_ringtone_notification","")));
        prefnoti.setSummary(ringtonenoti.getTitle(getActivity()));

        PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {

        Preference pref = findPreference(key);

        if(pref instanceof RingtonePreference)
        {
            Ringtone ringtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(context,Uri.parse(sharedPreferences.getString(key,"")));
            pref.setSummary(ringtone.getTitle(context));
        }

    }
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();

    startActivity(new Intent(SettingsActivity.this,MainActivity.class));SettingsActivity.this.finish();
}


@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
}
}
```

Activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.atulk.createcustomsettings.MainActivity">

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Start Settings"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:id="@+id/startsettings"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.502"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.095" />

 </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

custompreferences.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<PreferenceCategory
    android:title="User Details"
    android:key="key_user_details">

    <Preference
        android:key="key_user_name"
        android:title="User First Name"
        android:summary="John Smith"/>

    <Preference
        android:key="key_user_emailid"
        android:title="User Email ID"
        android:summary="asd@asd.com"/>

</PreferenceCategory>

<PreferenceCategory
    android:title="Sounds &amp; Notifications"
    android:key="key_sounds_settings">

    <RingtonePreference
        android:key="key_ringtone_alarm"
        android:title="Alarm Ringtone"
        android:ringtoneType="alarm"/>

    <RingtonePreference
        android:key="key_ringtone_notification"
        android:title="Notification"
        android:ringtoneType="notification"/>

    <SwitchPreference
        android:title="Vibrate"
        android:summary="Virate during Alarm or Notification"
        android:key="key_vibrate_onoff"/>

</PreferenceCategory>

<PreferenceCategory
    android:title="Message Delivery"
    android:key="key_message_delivery">

    <SwitchPreference
        android:title="Shorten SMS"
        android:summary="Reduce SMS length by using slangs"
        android:key="key_shorten_sms_length"/>

</PreferenceCategory>

</PreferenceScreen>
```

Comment: what kind of errors are you facing? have you registered a listener before unregistering it?

Comment: @nandsito   Where i try to add unregister in onPause or anywhere else it starts giving me context errors. i would appreciate if you could copy paste this project and check. Thx in advance.

Comment: i don't see where you are unregistering the listener and you could be possibly registering it. It is utmost important that you post the exact code or part of it that is causing errors, or else no one will be able to reproduce your issue

Comment: I was adding it to OnPause after super statment. not mentioned in code posted above as above code is bug free as of now. Anyways i sorted the issue out. i separated the 2 classes of preferenceactivity and preferencefragment in 2 different files and then it worked fine.

Comment: if admin or moderators want then they can delete this question. Thx for your help everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Just create 2 different java files with preferenceactivity and preferencefragment
 and call PF from PA with getFragmentManager routine. Rest all will work fine. Also use UnregisterOnPreferenceChangeListener in OnDestroy instead of OnPause.